# Grouping By with missing data

Tags: email, google-sheets

Image of Data and desired result:

[image: Image of Data and desired result]

I'm trying to aggregate volunteer hours from a Google spreadsheet a non-profit I volunteer for. We collect volunteer e-mail information and the time that each volunteer has contributed. Each volunteer only puts in their e-mail the first time. I've found examples online on how to send e-mails, but I'm having trouble aggregating the data. I think the trouble might be that not every row has an e-mail address associated with it.

I've been able to get the sum of hours worked by volunteer using `QUERY(data, "select A, sum(C) Group By A", )` but can't figure out how to get the e-mail associated with each individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the advice! The VLOOKUP and ArrayFormula functions were new to me. Here's how I solved it:

`QUERY(data, "select A, B where B <>'' ", -1)`

This allowed me to get the Key-Value pair (Name, Email) for each volunteer (solving the problem of people who volunteered multiple times, but only left their e-mail once). From there, I was able to generate the 'Name:Hours Worked' table off to the right with:

`QUERY(data, "select A, sum(C) Group By A", )`.

Then, I used VLOOKUP to query my Name-Email table to get the desired result of:

Name-Email-aggregatedHours

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve this with `query`. But you could apply `vlookup` to sorted table:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),SORT(A2:B,2,0),2,0))`

and get email list for unique names.

Comment: This doesn't aggregate the time that each volunteer has contributed.

Comment: The combination of vlookup to the table built by query was extremely helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. First, clean up your data. You shoud be certain that at least one column has no typos an that this column appropiate identify which data corresponds to each volunteer. This is called [key value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key-value_database). This also could be done by, but not limited to, filling up the missing values for each row. If this will be hard, then
2. Create a volunteer list without missing data.
3. Calculate the time contributed by each volunteer. If you was able to fill up the missing values, then you could use QUERY, I this case the QUERY formula should have to group by name and email, if not, then use [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I struggled with how to solve the missing data, but I was able to figure it out, as shown in the code above.